# Are there any other brain wallet generators like warp wallet?

Tags: brain-wallet

I'm looking for brain wallet implementations like warp wallet. Are there other brain wallet implementations that involve stressing the computer in order to generate a bitcoin address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forked the original warp wallet implementation and made it a bit more UX friendly for printable paper wallets that also supports segwit addresses:

Code: https://github.com/xcubicle/memorypaperwallet

Github Site: https://xcubicle.github.io/memorypaperwallet/

Answer (score 0):

You can use any algorithm you like to generate a 256-bit hash.

For example, you can go to this site to generate a PBKDF2 hash, using as many iterations as you like:  https://www.freecodeformat.com/pbkdf2.php

From there, you can copy the hexadecimal result to the bitaddress.org site, or use it as entropy data at the Ian Coleman BIP39 site, and generate an entire tree of private keys.

Regardless of your key stretching algorithm, you had better be certain you start with an extremely strong brainwallet password, and be able to readily remember it.  My shortest brainwallet password is over 40 characters long.  My longest is 101 characters long.  None of my passwords resemble book excerpts, song lyrics, limericks, or common idioms, in any language.  Yes, they are all committed to memory.

Comment: normal average joe's are not going to do this.

Comment: Everyone should keep the following article in perspective if they are going to use brain wallets: 
https://rya.nc/files/cracking_cryptocurrency_brainwallets.pdf

Comment: My answer isn't directed at average Joes.  Most people should just secure their 12 or 24 word seed and be done with it.  I'm personally not happy with doing doing it that way, though.  I've been doing my own brainwallets since 2015, and prefer generating my own passwords.  I originally did it out of the fear of losing my private keys.  BIP39 didn't exist yet.  I learned what I could about passwords, password storage, and password cracking, and constructed robust passwords accordingly, then applied it to brainwallets.  I've been pretty happy with the results.